# Avoiding Infinite Loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-loop

I'm quite a newbie, so forgive my ignorance. I am trying to, through local storage, get a timer to tell the user when they last visited the page. But I have instead made an infinite loop, how do I correct this? calling the function outside the function? What would this look like?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myDate = new Date(2015,4,9,0,0);
    localStorage["mydate"] = JSON.stringify(myDate);

    startTimer();
});

function startTimer() {
    setInterval(function(){
    var text = "It's been " + hoursSinceFirstVisit() + " hours since you first visited.";
    $('#timer').text(text);
 }, 1000);
}

function hoursSinceFirstVisit() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var lastDate = new Date(JSON.parse(localStorage["mydate"]));
    return hoursBetweenDates( lastDate, currentDate);
}
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Your code will simply update the hours since your first visit every second. Is that not what you want? Where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: Ok, I ran your script in Chrome and Firefox and it seems to work fine. I never ran into a "too much recursion" error. What you could try is ommiting the JSON part. Just use `myDate.toISOString()` to convert your date object into string representation and then use `new Date(localStorage["mydate"])` to get back the date object.

Comment: Sweet, if I wanted to troubleshoot the JSON... where would I begin?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying that it works without JSON and now you want to make it work with JSON?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `hoursBetweenDates` function provided, so I added one. For debugging recursion errors, try moving the anonymous function to a named function as it is called repeatedly. Break code into smaller parts and make sure no part repeatedly calls itself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myDate = new Date(2015, 4, 9, 0, 0);
  localStorage.mydate = JSON.stringify(myDate);

  function startTimer() {
    setInterval(updateMessage, 100);
  }

  function updateMessage() {
    var text = "It's been " + hoursSinceFirstVisit() + " hours since you first visited.";
    $('#timer').text(text);
  }

  // This is my function for getting hours between dates
  function hoursBetweenDates(d1, d2) {
    return Math.abs(d1 - d2) / 36e5;

    // For integer hours use this function
    // return Math.floor(Math.abs(d1 - d2) / 36e5);
  }

  function hoursSinceFirstVisit() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var lastDate = new Date(JSON.parse(localStorage.mydate));
    return hoursBetweenDates(lastDate, currentDate);
  }

  startTimer();
});
```

This will work fine without recursion errors. Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/demevi/3/). Note, I made it return hours with decimal precision since the last visit, and set the interval to 100 ms to demonstrate it works fine. Update your version as you like. Apologies, I could not make a Stack Snippet because local storage is disabled.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/demevi/3/

Comment: Thanks! The split seconds racing by looked awesome! Now I have to edit it *out for just hours : )

Comment: What is supposed to be the advantage of moving all the code in `$(document).ready()` and declaring the `updateMessage` function a level higher? I don't see the point.

Comment: @BarrenessBogdanoff use `Math.floor(Math.abs(d1 - d2) / 36e5);`

Comment: @basilikum For debugging recursion errors. You seem to be in love with this question. Nothing else to do?

Comment: Well you made it sound like there is something wrong with writing `setTimeout(function () {})` which it is not. You didn't mention that the reasons were debugging puroses. Which makes sense. But in that case, your answer really just should be a comment, since you're actually not answering the question. And how I spend my time is my business.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) schedules a function to be executed repeatedly, waiting a specified number of milliseconds before each run.

If you want to delay the execution of function `hoursSinceFirstVisit()` (and run it only once) then you have to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```
function startTimer() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       var text = "It's been " + hoursSinceFirstVisit() + " hours since you first visited.";
       $('#timer').text(text);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: When I tried this I am still getting too much recursion in Firefox and Max call stack size exceeded in Chrome... sry, where did you place this function in my script?

Comment: It's always this line:

Comment: var lastDate = new Date(JSON.parse(localStorage["mydate"]));

Comment: With this error in Chrome:                                                                                               Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded